# Installing Tangible T4 Editor in VS 2010 RC

Tags: visual-studio, t4, tangible-t4-editor

I installed the (free) ***Tangible T4 Editor*** from the VS Gallery, and shut down/restarted VS. I run on XP under an Administrator account. VS Extension Manager indicates that the editor is installed and enabled.

Here is my problem: When I do ***Add New Item*** (as in the video [**here**](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html)), I don't see any of the Tangible templates. What have I missed?

(BTW, I looked around some more, found the ***T4 Toolbox***, installed that, and still see no new templates for Tangible or the toolbox).

Thanks!

Comment: Received this response from Tangible rep -- 

...everything is alright with your install. Indeed some of the guidance is refferíng to the VS2008 Version which comes with more templates and UML Tools.
In VS2010 we only provide the Editor as of now and VS itself comes with a Template Called “Text Template” in the normal add dialog.

We are adding more features to vS2010 version soon to achieve feature parity.

As of now the best thing you can do is to visit olegsych.com and learn from the articles there about T4 and also look at our How Do I Videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[T4 Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com) doesn't support 2010 RC just yet. Stay tuned.

Comment: Awesome news Oleg, thanks! I would upvote you but I don't have enough points yet :(

Answer (score 0):

T4 Editor for 2010 assumes you use the default template "Text Template" that is installed with VS2010 itself. Another option is to use the T4 Toolbox from Oleg which now supports VS2010 RC. Additional templates will be available in the editors template gallery at RTM of VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

The tangible T4 Editor is now available for VS2010 RTM
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/60297607-5fd4-4da4-97e1-3715e90c1a23